# How do i write and execute FASM code in VS Code

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code, fasm

At the University where I study, we are taught Assembly language. My teacher told us to use Fasm,but I would like to use visual studio code to write programs. I downloaded the Retro Assembler extension, but it tries to find the file retroassembler.exe which just doesn't exist. I carefully read the instructions for installing the extension,but could not find any clues. What am I missing?

Maybe you know more convenient solutions for creating programs on Fasm. Anyway I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one answered the question, and I have already found a solution myself, it is worth describing it. I hope there are people in this world who have encountered my problem.

In any case, RetroAssembler extension in VScode does not download assembler itself. You can find it [here](https://enginedesigns.net/retroassembler/) at the bottom of the page. Then you need to unpack it and specify the path where you used to unpack it in your VScode settings (File=>Preferences=>Settings=>Extensions=>RetroAssembler).

Have a good time learning assembler!